# Python Playwright make code reload page after timeout until it finds the object

Tags: python, automation, playwright

I want the code to reload the page if it doesn't find the desired object (e.g. a button) after a given timeout time. The code should reload the page until it finds the object and then continue. Is there any way to do it in python playwright?

I've read the documentation, but I didn't find anything, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own function like this one:

```
def my_own_wait_for_selector(page, selector, time_out):
    try:
        page.wait_for_selector(selector, timeout=time_out)
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

That function will wait for a selector and if given some time (miliseconds) the element is not there it will return `False` instead of trowing an error.

Then in your code you could try something like:

```
while not my_own_wait_for_selector(page, "my_button_selector", 5000):
    page.reload()
page.locator("my_button_selector").click()
```

As you can see we are checking if our button is present, and we will wait only 5 seconds, if after 5 seconds the button is not there, we will reload, and again and again until our button is there, once our button is there code will continue and then we will click the button.

Be careful, because if your button is never there, your script will reload and your script will never finish, so you should add some other condition to your while